# Delete one-sided conversations

Tags: sql, sqlite, sqlperformance

I am creating a mobile application where I store data into sqlite, where the performance is very important.
In order to delete one-side conversation, I am using the following query:

```
delete from messages where id in (
    select id from messages where sender_id not in(
        select recipient_id from messages
    )
    union 
    select id from messages where recipient_id not in(
        select sender_id from messages
    )
 )
```

But I profiled it and found that it took about 2 seconds to delete about 800 records.
So please help me to write another query faster.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: You want all messages from senders that haven't received a message and those from all recipients that haven't sent a message?

Comment: @vMai, Yes you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The separate ID lookup step is not necessary:

```
DELETE FROM messages
WHERE sender_id    NOT IN (SELECT recipient_id FROM messages)
   OR recipient_id NOT IN (SELECT sender_id    FROM messages)
```

Furthermore, the lookups are faster when you add indexes to the `sender_id` and `recipient_id` columns.